# Smoothly homotopic is an equivalence relation

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

I was wondering if somebody could point me to a resource which proves the fact that two functions being smoothly homotopic is an equivalence relation. It is easy when the homotopy $H:X\times [0,1] \rightarrow Y$ between two functions $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:X\rightarrow Y$ need only be continuous, but seems less than straightforward when it is required to be smooth as well.

The hard part is of course transitivity. I found one reference here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Smooth_Homotopy_is_an_Equivalence_Relation , but this seems to require some assumptions on the range space $Y$ that are not clearly stated. Specifically, it defines two homotopies

$A(x,t)= \phi(t) g(x) + (1-\phi(t))f(x)$
and

$B(x,t)= \phi(t) h(x) + (1-\phi(t))g(x)$,

but if we take $t=\frac{1}{2}$ in either, then we get, for example,
$A(x,\frac{1}{2})= f(x)+\phi(\frac{1}{2})(g(x)-f(x))$, which does not need to necessarily be in the range space $Y$ unless it $Y$ is assumed convex.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here. Thanks!

Comment: What does $+$ mean?

Comment: Great question. Again, it doesn't seem that this proof is very good unless we assume more structure on the range space $Y$. Do you know of a more general proof?

Comment: Minimally, "smooth" has to make sense, so $Y$ (and $X$) must at least be a manifold.

Comment: You could use the fact that any maps that are homotopic are smoothly homotopic. You can look at Lee Lemma 6.28 and Theorem 6.29. Lemma 6.28 does exactly what Angina Seng's answer does but perhaps is more visual due to the diagram of $\phi$ given.

Answer (score 3):

The usual trick is to replace the homotopy $H$ by a homotopy which is "constant"
for $t$ near zero and $t$ near $1$. Then two such homotopies can be spliced
without losing smoothness at the join.

We assume $X$ and $Y$ are smooth manifolds.

To be more precise we want to find a smooth homotopy $H':X\times I\to Y$
with the property that $H'(x,t)=H'(x,0)$ for $t\in[0,1/3]$ and
$H'(x,t)=H'(x,1)$ for $t\in[2/3,1]$. To do this define
$$H'(x,t)=H(x,\phi(t))$$
where $H$ is your original homotopy, $\phi$ is a smooth function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$
with $\phi\equiv0$ on $[0,1/3]$, $\phi\equiv1$ on $[2/3,1]$ and $\phi(t)\in[0,1]$
in all cases. One can construct such a function by taking the indefinite
integral of a suitable smooth "bump function".

Comment: I think I follow the logic..I found a better reference here: https://books.google.com/books?id=SMBeDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=%22smooth%22+homotopy+%22equivalence+relation%22+proof&source=bl&ots=Ctjxywc4bR&sig=ACfU3U23Vx5WinGJTLhaVLuAOyNQHpU21A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS7IujjoTqAhXBRjABHYKNBBo4ChDoATAFegQICRAB#v=onepage&q&f=false

In this result (Lemma 23), I still fail to see why the $L(t,x)$, so defined, is automatically smooth at $(x,t)$ such that $t=\frac{1}{2}$.