# Combining two homotopies in linear time

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose $f,g,h:M\to N$ are smooth maps such that $f\sim g$ and $g\sim h$. I.e. there are smooth homotopies
$$F:M\times I\to N,\qquad G:M\times I\to N,$$
such that
$$F(x,0)=f, F(x,1)=g,\qquad G(x,0)=g, G(x,1)=h$$

I want to know what is the problem with the following homotopy between $f$ and $h$? Isn't smooth?
$$H(x,t)=\begin{cases}F(x,2t), & t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]\\ G(x,2t-1), & t\in[\frac{1}{2},1]\end{cases}$$

I am asking this in regard to Milnor construction of $f\sim h$ using bump function in *Topology from differentiable viewpoint*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smoothly homotopic is an equivalence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720814/smoothly-homotopic-is-an-equivalence-relation)

Comment: This fails because reparametrized may not match smoothly at $t=1/2$. See lemma 23 of https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SMBeDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=%22smooth%22+homotopy+%22equivalence+relation%22+proof&source=bl&ots=Ctjxywc4bR&sig=ACfU3U23Vx5WinGJTLhaVLuAOyNQHpU21A&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thanks. first link I think is not same as mine.

Comment: I think you can a make counterexample in your own very quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not smooth at $1/2$. Take for instance $M = \{0\}$ and $N = \Bbb R$, with $F(0,t) = t$ and $G(0, t) = 1-t$. The graph of your $H$

One can overcome "cusps" like this as Milnor does by slowing down to a stop at the cusp-point before moving on to the next part of the curve.

Comment: What are the $f,g,h$ here?

Comment: You meant it is not smooth at $0.5$ considering it as a function from $[0,1]\to ?$?

Comment: Another example, Let $M=\Bbb R^n=N$, and $f\equiv c_1,g\equiv c_2,h\equiv c_2$ be constants. Let $\gamma_1:[0,1]\to \Bbb R^n$ be a smooth path from $c_1$ to $c_2$ and $\gamma_2:[0,1]\to \Bbb R^n$ be another smooth path from $c_2$ to $c_3$. Let $F(\bullet, t)=\gamma_1(t)$ and $G(\bullet, t)=\gamma_2(t)$. You can choose $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ so that $\gamma_2*\gamma_1$ is not smooth at $1/2$.